Automatically save all printed files to PDF
I have a custom MS Access tool that creates and prints documents to the default printer.
What's the best way to save every printed file from this tool to PDF in addition to printing it?

Set your default printer to Print-To-PDF. Are you asking how to make THIS TOOL "print" every file to PDF and other applications be able to print however you prefer, or to save PDFs in addition to printing them to a printer, or do you want every program to print pdfs regardless which printer is set default? Please add more details and specifics to your question. Right now it is very general and broad, and this sort of question is difficult to answer beyond the generic "change your default printer to Print to PDF"

If you want to create 1 pdf with multiple prints merged, try PDF Creator

Some printer drivers offer the ability to perform additional actions besides outputting to their printer, but this is not a default behavior of Windows or very common among printer drivers. You could try a printing utility that creates a virtual printer and allows some more complex document routing functions, but the names of these escape me at the moment.
